# c3js timeseries chart interval colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, c3.js, timeserieschart

I'm starting with the c3.js library and I want to make a time chart (timeseries) and color-code the values based on some intervals. I receive the data from a json after making a query in PHP. I make an array for the dates and an array for the values, and receive them in the javascript function to make the chart like so:

```
let xData = (data.date);
let yData = (data.value);

xData.unshift('x');
yData.unshift('Values');
var chart7 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart7',
    data: {
        x:'x',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        columns:[
            xData,
            yData
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
        x:{
            label:{
                text:'Date',
                position:'outer-center'
            },
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick:{
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        },
    },
    point: {
        show: true,
        //r:3.5
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    color: {
        pattern: ['#b7b485', '#0E6A40', '#B73540', '#B73540']
    },
     padding: {
        top: 5,
        right: 5,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 30,
    },
    size:{
        height:240,
    }
});
```

the json data would be something like this: (I give an example):

```
 ['x', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06', '2022-05-07', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-09', '2022-05-10', '2022-05-12', '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16', '2022-05-17', '2022-05-18', '2022-05-19', '2022-05-20', '2022-05-21']
```

```
 ['Values', '0.0249', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0094', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0011', '0.0011', '0.0011', '0.0006', '0.0042', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0011', '0.0011']
```

I want to be able to put them in three colors, green, yellow and red based on an intervals
**if the value is less than 0.3: green color
if the value is greater than 0.3 and less than 0.6: yellow color
if the value is greater than 0.6: red color**
I don't know if this is possible. I thought about creating 6 arrays already in php 3 for dates and 3 for values, but when trying to put them in the graph I was not able to represent them. If I put a single 'x' for a date, it gave me several values and it couldn't be because these values are unique.
Does anyone know how I can represent color intervals?

Comment: the documentation of c3js give information about a color callback argument: https://c3js.org/samples/data_color.html does that meet your needs?

Comment: I had seen it in the examples, it might work if I was able to use: date1, value1, date2, value2, date3, value3 (arrays)- date1-2-3 on the timeline @PandaBlue

Comment: hum, indeed, the elemennt generated is a single line (path) with a class like c3-line-data1, so if you add some d3js shenanigan, you might be able to add a gradient to approximate what you would like to do: https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_color_gradient_svg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
color: (_, d) => d.value < 0.3 ? '#0E6A40': d.value < 0.6 ? '#b7b485' : '#B73540'
```

Here's your example adapted - I used other intervals to fit your example and a more elaborate `color` function to control the color outside the plot itself (e.g., in the legend) as the the last one (red).

```js
let xData = ['x', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06', '2022-05-07', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-09', '2022-05-10', '2022-05-12', '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16', '2022-05-17', '2022-05-18', '2022-05-19', '2022-05-20', '2022-05-21']
let yData =  ['Values', '0.0249', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0094', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0066', '0.0011', '0.0011', '0.0011', '0.0006', '0.0042', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0163', '0.0011', '0.0011'];
let _defVal = 1;    
const chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart7',
    data: {
        x:'x',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        columns:[
            xData,
            yData
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        color: (_, d) => {const val = d.value ?? _defVal; return val < 0.003 ? '#0E6A40': val < 0.006 ? '#b7b485' : '#B73540'}
    },
    axis: {
        x:{
            label:{
                text:'Date',
                position:'outer-center'
            },
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick:{
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        format:{
            value: function(val){
                _defVal = val;
                return ''+val
            }
        }
    },
    point: {
        show: true,
        //r:3.5
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    padding: {
        top: 5,
        right: 5,
        bottom: 5,
        left: 30,
    },
    size:{
        height:240,
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.0.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.7.20/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="chart7"></div>
```

Comment: Note that the graph type changed, from lines to bars. With bars it works perfectly, each bar is 1 svg object, and you can control the color individualy. For lines, all the data creates only 1 path

Comment: @PandaBlue what do you mean, changed? Wasn't it bars in the OP's question?

Comment: when I tried to produce his graph, I got a line, but as I rewrote it, I may have made an error, sorry

Comment: Yes, it's what I needed. I got to see the color function, but I didn't know how to apply it. Looking at the code now I understand it differently.
Thank you very much @kikon

Comment: Thaks! @PandaBlue, I will also see the example of gradients in line graphs, I find it very interesting.